# How do I pass the SQL Server Job name to a stored procedure inside this job?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, token, sql-job

I have a job:

RunProcedures

It has steps:

Step 1: Do Something
Step 2: Do something Else
Step 3: Email

In step 3, I have:

```
EXEC spSendSuccessEmail -- and here's where I want to pass the job name.
```

Here's the code for the stored procedure above:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spSendSuccessEmail] @JobName VARCHAR(30)
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @EmailBody VARCHAR(50)

    SET @EmailBody = @JobName + ' ran successfully'

    BEGIN TRY
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
            @profile_name = 'DBTeam',
            @recipients = 'user@universe.com',
            @copy_recipients = 'user2@universe.com',
            @subject = 'Process Complete',
            @body = @EmailBody,
            @importance = 'Normal',
            @sensitivity = 'Normal';
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        EXEC spGetDatabaseErrorInfo
    END CATCH           
END
```

How do I pass to this stored procedure the name of the job it's in?

I read on tokens but I'm a little confused on how to accomplish this task.

Can anyone give me a hand?

Comment: Exec spSendSuccessEamil @Jobname. assumes variable is declared, set from earlier, and is a string type. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE**
I did some testing and for some versions of SQL Server(2005 sp1 and beyond), you'll have to escape the Token.  I've added the escape command to the code below.

$(JOBID) is the [token](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175575.aspx) you want to use, and you can query from msdb..sysjobs to find the job name.

For sql server 2005 sp1 and beyond:

```
declare @jobName varchar(100)

select @jobName = name from msdb..sysjobs where job_id = $(ESCAPE_NONE(JOBID))

exec spSendSuccessEamil @jobName
```

For sql server 2005 and earlier:

```
declare @jobName varchar(100)

select @jobName = name from msdb..sysjobs where job_id = $(JOBID)

exec spSendSuccessEamil @jobName
```

Just use one of these as your command text within the 3rd step of your job.

Comment: this actually did not work :( ... first, I think you meant to put "SELECT" before the "name" column. for some reason $(ESCAPE_NONE(JOBID)) is being underlined when I try to assign it to @JobName. it keeps saying incorrect name.

Comment: hmm, i pasted the first 2 lines of sql directly into my job and they worked fine.  What version of sql server are you using?  If it's earlier than 2005 service pack 1, try removing the ESCAPE_NONE, so that it is just "job_id = $(JOBID)".  ESCAPE_NONE may not exist in earlier versions of sql server.

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2012 and this worked like a charm, thank you!